# Issues with artifactory Docker

Tags: docker, artifactory

We went ahead and setup the reverse proxy so that we can create a docker repo in artifactory. When attempting to log into artifactory we get the following error.

docker login domain.com

Username: user

Password:

Error response from daemon: Get domain.com/v2/: invalid token auth challenge realm: parse domain.com:PORT#/api/docker/docker-repo/v2/token: missing protocol scheme

Has anyone had this error before?

Regards,

Moe

Comment: As far as I understand, this error appears when docker could not connect to the remote repo. Should be a network issue.

Comment: What proxy are you using?
What version of that proxy are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory uses the value of the X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url header for forming the URL. If it's not properly formatted you get this response/error.

Artifactory itself suggests a configuration snippet for your Apache front end web server, which contains 2.4 specific features (notably my_scheme.) If you use it in a 2.2 (or older) installation it will be empty.